# GRaaarrgghhh.... content not displaying

Tags: jquery

OK, i have this page on my DEV server and it works just fine... when i publish to PROD it just doesnt display...

can anyone see WTF is going on...?  I have re published, modified, stripped down...etc... and can not get it to work...

https://www.bcidaho.com/about_us/reduce-healthcare-costs.asp

there should be a content slider there that shows 10 DIVS of content... and its about to make me smash my keyboard.

thanx

Comment: Have you considered differences in how your browser treats your dev environment vs. your prod environment? Maybe one is in the intranet zone while the other is Internet. The difference in security settings could impact how the content is rendered (including whether or not compatibility mode is active).

Comment: The question is unspecific. How is your dev different from prod? What is the simpliest case you can reproduce, have you cleared caches, etc...

Comment: Please do give more information.  Exactly what renders differently?  Have you focused in on a particular component that renders in one environment and not the other?  Is the underlying HTML the same in both environments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem Solved.

Z-Index was set to -100 on the cs-slider to drop it behind the navigation drop down, however that placed it behind the centercol, so i wasnt displaying.

Comment: It may be prudent to mark this answer as an actual accepted answer, to remove this question from the Unanswered queue.